# Theming stuff in Drupal 8?

Tags: 8

How do you theme stuff in Drupal 8? In 7, for example, if you had some data items you could call item_list, via the theme function, pass in a render array and get your markup back.

This is a great resource for those interested: [Render API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21theme.api.php/group/theme_render/8), but no examples that I can see.

How do I do this in Drupal 8? For example, how do I theme an image? Sure,
I can probably construct my render array, but does it then have to go off to a twig template or something. Are there any examples yet?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

It seems to be similar to D7. Just use a render array:

```
$list = array('apples', 'peaches', 'pears');
$render_array = array(
  '#theme' => 'item_list',
  '#items' => $list,
  '#title' => t('Argument Information'),
);
return $render_array;
```

I searched *'#theme'* in *core\modules* to find examples. Not sure if this is the 'correct' way though?

Comment: Yes, it works exactly like in D7 if you use render arrays. Whenever possible, use render arrays, if you really can't (e.g. in hook_help() or other places that can't return a render array), you can use \Drupal::theme()->render() as a replacement for theme().